# Chrome auto-focuses on (and selects) address bar when opening new browser window

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have a minor nuisance with Chrome that I am hoping somebody else has a solution to.

I am running Google Chrome (version 30) on Windows 7.

When I open Chrome it immediately puts the focus on the address bar and I immediately start typing whatever I want to search for (lets say, "halloween costumes for kids", or "hwll sfdwer fsddfw fwersdf").

[image]

In the mean time, Chrome is still loading, and eventually (a couple seconds later) it finishes opening the new tab page. Upon fully loading the new tab page, it then selects whatever I have already typed in the search bar (e.g. "halloween custumes fo" or "hwll sfdwer" as in the picture) and the very next character I hit, it wipes out whatever I already had typed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is your new tab page taking so long to open, but one thing you can do is that instead of opening a new tab and then start typing the new url or search query, that you go to the search bar and type whatever it is you're looking for, and instead of pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, and this will open a new tab and open the url or search query that you entered in the existing tab.